# How to compute conditional mean on uniform distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Suppose we have a tuple which is uniformly distributed on the given set below.

$$(X,Y)\sim \operatorname{unif}\{(-2,0),(-2,-2),(0,-1),(0,0),(1,0),(1,3)\} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$$

I just determined mean for $X$ and $Y$ which are respectively

$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\frac{-2+(-2)+0+0+1+1}{6}=\frac{1}{3}$$

$$\mathbb{E}[Y]=\frac{0+2+(-1)+0+0+3}{6}=\frac{2}{3}$$

Now I have to look at the conditional mean $\mathbb{E}[Y\mid X=a]$ with $a=-2,0,1$

[image]

So how do I compute conditional mean. I am not very experienced dealing with conditional problems

Comment: E.g. Given $X = -2$, you have $\displaystyle \Pr\{Y = 0\} = \Pr\{Y = 2\} = \frac {1/6} {1/6 + 1/6} = \frac {1} {2}$. After calculating the conditional probability (by "normalizing"), just calculate the mean as before and obtain $E[Y|X = -2] = -1$

Comment: Your computation of $\operatorname E(X)$ is wrong. Just from the picture you should see that it has to be a negative number.